# display of metadata hyperlink on list and views

Tags: metadata

For a column on my list, data is drawn from a metadata field. It works nicely, a tree is displayed, and the item is selected from the tree. An underlined value then goes into the column (presumably some kind of hyperlink) when a new item is added or in update mode. However, when the value is displayed in a list or in view mode it decomposes to text.

What is going on? How can the hyperlink be retained in the list, or in the item view? Additionally, how can I create a calculated column that can be used to display that column into decomposed text?

Comment: FYI, you get more credit and attention if you mark your questions as answered. Your questions posted in june have no answers, you may also answer your own question (instead of editting the question and adding a "answer" like you did; which does not mark a question as answered)

Comment: Thanks for this Danny... I've updated the other post as being answered and am still working on the other issues...